# Run nextflow pipeline multiple time depending on length of a list

Tags: bash, groovy, nextflow

I have a Nextflow pipeline that runs a BUSCO search on input data, returns the output and then creates a report based on the output. One of my parameters is the lineage dataset. I would like to have my pipeline run multiple times (preferably at the same time) based on how long my list of lineage datasets is. The goal is that my pipeline would run twice in this case. If there are n lineages specified I would like it to run n times. These are my files so far:

Nextflow.config

```
params { 
    input_files              = "$PWD/input_data/*.fasta"
    lineage_datasets        = ["fungi_odb10", "microsporidia_odb10"]
    augustus_species        = "fumigatus"
    mode                    = "geno"
    
    threads                 = 16
    help                    = false
    outdir {
        main                = "$PWD/results"
        intermediate        = "$launchDir/busco_outputs"
    }
}

process {
    executor                = 'slurm'
    cpus                    = 4
    time                    = '1hour'
    memory                  = '4.GB'
}

singularity {
    enabled                 = true
    autoMounts              = true
}
```

main.nf:

```
process busco {
  container "quay.io/biocontainers/busco:5.2.2--pyhdfd78af_0"

  tag "${lineage_dataset}: ${input_file.name}"

  input:
    path input_file
    each lineage_dataset
  
  output:
    path "hap1/short_summary.${lineage_dataset}.${output_name}.txt"

  script: 
  output_name = input_file.baseName

    """
    busco \
    -m ${params.mode} \
    -o hap1 \
    -i $input_file \
    -l ${lineage_dataset} \
    --augustus_species ${params.augustus_species} \
    --update-data \
    -c 8 \
    | echo "${params.augustus_species}" >> "./hap1/short_summary.${lineage_dataset}.${output_name}.txt"

    """
}

process createReport {

  publishDir params.outdir.main, mode: 'copy'

  input: 
    path "short_summary.*", stageAs: 'busco_outputs/*'

  output:
    path 'report.html'

  script:
    """
    source "$launchDir/venv/bin/activate"
    report.py > report.html
    """ 
}

workflow {
  input_files = Channel.fromPath(params.input_files)
  
  busco( input_files, params.lineage_datasets )
  | collect
  | createReport
}
```

report.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from report_modules.utils.report_utils import Report_Printer
from report_modules.utils.parsing_utils import Report_Parser
from pathlib import Path

projectDir = "/".join(__file__.split("/")[0:-2])
path = Path(f"{projectDir}/busco_outputs")
list_of_files = path.glob('*.txt')

file_data_array = []
for data in list_of_files:
    file_data = ""
    with open(data, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            file_data += line
    file_data_array.append(file_data)

all_stats_dicts = {}
for index, file_data in enumerate(file_data_array):
    parser = Report_Parser(file_data)
    stats_dict = parser.parse_report()
    all_stats_dicts[f'dict_{index}'] = stats_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    report_printer = Report_Printer()
    report_template = report_printer.print_template(all_stats_dicts)
```

This is what I currently have now (after editing my code) and I am hoping that each summary.txt file from busco will be passed into the createReport process inside of a folder called busco_outputs. The report.py script will then read the busco_outputs folder and loop through each of the summary files inside of it.

Please let me know what I should change in order to have this working properly! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is outside my area of expertise, but if you don't get an answer on stackoverflow, I highly recommend the folks over at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question

Answer (score 3):

You get the error because `params.lineage_datasets` is an `ArrayList`, but the [`cross`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#cross) operator requires a target channel in order to combine the items. That said, I think there are some other issues that need addressing first:

- List params are not (yet) supported, so there's no way to specify multiple lineage datasets from the command line using the current approach. Instead, you will likely want to pass in a string of comma-separated lineages so they can be split/tokenized.
- Know that files are copied to the [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) *asynchronously*, so downstream processes should not try to access files in the publish directory. Ensure your `createReport` process therefore avoids targeting files in this directory. Usually you do not want to publish intermediary files anyway, so your BUSCO process can probably omit the publishDir directive altogether.

Here's one way, using the [each](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-repeaters-each) input repeater, that address the above. I'm not sure if I've got the summary output filename pattern correct, so you may need to adjust accordingly:

```
params.sequence_files = "./input_data/*.fasta"
params.lineage_datasets = "fungi_odb10,microsporidia_odb10"
params.outdir = "./results"
```

```
process BUSCO {

    tag "${lineage_dataset}: ${sequence_file.name}"

    input:
    path sequence_file
    each lineage_dataset

    output:
    path "short_summary.${lineage_dataset}.${output_name}.txt"

    script:
    output_name = sequence_file.baseName

    """
    touch short_summary.${lineage_dataset}.${output_name}.txt
    """
}
```

```
process createReport {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/report", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path summary_files, stageAs: 'summary_files/*'

    output:
    path 'report.html'

    """
    source "$launchDir/venv/bin/activate"
    report.py --summary_files ${summary_files} > report.html
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    lineage_datasets = params.lineage_datasets?.tokenize(',')

    sequence_files = Channel.fromPath( params.sequence_files )

    outputs = BUSCO( sequence_files, lineage_datasets )

    createReport( outputs.collect() )
}
```

Comment: Sometimes when I see your answers, I feel like deleting mine haha. Pretty good, Steve!

Comment: Thanks @mribeirodantas, I wouldn't delete it - it's nice to know that we both came to the same conclusion!

Comment: Thank you so much this is super helpful and helps me to understand how the each operator can be used to run through multiple tokens :)

Ive actually updated my question to include my full busco search code as it's still not working correctly! Thanks again!

Comment: No worries @CornOnTheCob, I'll take a look and update my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks again @Steve !! I've now overhauled my code to incorporate most of what you've suggested. Look forward to your update :) Thanks!

Comment: @CornOnTheCob I had trouble running BUSCO and reproducing your results. For example, I get errors like `Cannot reach https://busco-data.ezlab.org/v5/data/file_versions.tsv` using the container quay.io container. I tried the lastest BUSCO, `ezlabgva/busco:v5.4.4_cv1`, but I also got errors with `--augustus_species`:  `Impossible to locate the species "fumigatus" in Augustus species folder`. If you can let me know what I need or just include a list of BUSCO output files for one BUSCO process, I might be able to suggest a suitable output declaration.

Comment: @CornOnTheCob I also don't understand why you need the `| echo "${params.augustus_species}" .... `. I suspect you don't need this.

Comment: @CornOnTheCob And in your Python code, I don't think you need to specify a projectDir variable. Why not just use `path = Path("./busco_outputs")`? Or perhaps, feed in directory variable on the command line using `argparse`? Consider also wrapping your code using a function called `main` so it can just be called in the usual way, using: `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`.

Comment: Thanks so much again!!! I wasn't able to test this yesterday because apparently the link to the file_versions.tsv wasn't available on the busco website so no one could run BUSCO. The reason I want to echo the augustus species is because I want it appended to the output file so I can parse that with my python script as it does not appear in the standard BUSCO output file.

Comment: The reason I used projectDir is because I need to locate the busco_outputs folder from the folder which contains the report.py script. I think it is something to do withhow nextflow passes processes into the work folders. But I will try it with your method and also implement the main function too!! Thank you again for your help you are unbelievably helpful!!! Is there some other way I could potentially contact you? @Steve

Comment: No worries at all, @CornOnTheCob! IMO, pipelining tools that rely on access to external files/data isn't ideal. My preference would be to disable this behavior somehow, if at all possible. Note that `params.augustus_species` is global and can just be accessed from within the `createReport` process. Better to just pass it in on the command line using `argparse` I think.

Comment: @CornOnTheCob So Nextflow runs each of it's processes isolated from each other in the working directory (ie. `./work`). When a process is run, Nextflow calls a file called `.command.run` which basically just sets up the environment, localizes the declared input files, and runs the actual script commands in `.command.sh`. Using the `stageAs: 'busco_outputs/*'` option lets you control how these input files are named inside this directory. So when `report.py` is called, the input files are localized under `./busco_outputs` in the $PWD. Avoid accessing files outside of the workdir and you're good.

Comment: Also, I think change `source "$launchDir/venv/bin/activate"` to `source "${projectDir}/venv/bin/activate"` and move the virtual env to the directory containing your `main.nf`. That way, all the necessary files can be included alongside with the workflow, see: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html

Comment: We can move this to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) now that you have enough rep :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251059/discussion-between-steve-and-cornonthecob).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're looking for the [`each` qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=each#input-repeaters-each). Your process block should look like:

```
...

  input:
  path inputFile
  each lineage_dataset

...
```

The `each` qualifier makes the process start a new task for every value of the `lineage_dataset` collection, keeping everything else the same. Check the example below:

```
process listOfBeverages {
  debug true
  input:
  val beverage
  each temperatures

  """
  echo $temperatures $beverage
  """
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .of('Coca-cola', 'Coffee', 'Orange Juice')
    .set { beverages }

  temperatures = ['hot', 'cold']

  listOfBeverages(beverages, temperatures)
}
```

The output:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.4
Launching `ex.nf` [thirsty_lavoisier] DSL2 - revision: 9a4e72fc82
executor >  local (6)
[55/5cfce4] process > listOfBeverages (1) [100%] 6 of 6 ✔
cold Coffee

cold Orange Juice

hot Orange Juice

cold Coca-cola

hot Coffee

hot Coca-cola
```